# Rails: submitting a form without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-earth

My app (https://showthatview.herokuapp.com/) has two parts:

- A Google Earth pane, where a view is shown
- A form, where the user sets the address / height where he wants the camera to be set

When the user submits the form, I want the RoR back end to store the parameters set by the user, and the JS front end to update the view. I got the two separate parts working.

When the user submits the Rail forms, it reloads the page and "resets" the camera

Ideally I want the form to submit the data to the back end without reloading the page - is this possible? Or maybe I'm doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Not here - you mean I should?

Comment: @FrancescoBovoli he meant, hot do you send ajax requests?

Comment: Adding `remote: true` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting some of your code would help, but try adding "remote: true" to your form. That will tell your page not to refresh upon submitting.

Furthermore, you will need to create a new method in your controller to forward to that responds to your submission and a page in your views folder (probably a js.erb file) that reloads the data.
Without seeing your code, a quick example of the steps:

app/assets/views/google_earth/index.html.erb

`<%= form_for(@pane_view, url: camera_path, remote: true) do |f| %>`

In your routes file:

```
get 'camera' => 'google_earth#cameraUpdate', as: 'camera'
```

app/assets/views/google_earth/camera.js.erb

```
$('#camera-pane').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'camera_view', :locals => { x_coord: @x, y_coord: @y }) %>");
```

This is assuming you have a partial view for your pane, I recommend doing it as a partial if you haven't already:
app/assets/views/google_earth/_camera_view.html.erb

Finally, in your controller you will want:

```
def cameraUpdate
  @x = params[:x_coordinate]
  @y = params[:y_coordinate]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, remote:true was what I was missing. Also explained in the Rails documentation that I found here (after you put me on the right rack): http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for

Answer (score 0):

#### With jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "/get_some_route/", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

#### With Rails:

**xxx.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Daily Collection', 'daily_collection', class: "btn btn-info", method: 'get', remote: true %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get   'daily_collection' => 'patients#daily_collection'
```

**patients_controller.rb**

```
class Patients
   def daily_collection
      do something...
   end
end
```

**collection_money.html.erb**

```
<p>to be appended with the called page </p>
```

**daily_collection.js.erb**

```
$('#price_daily').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'collection_money') %>');
```

#### for more reference:

- [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)
- [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)