# Use Rails logic with JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

This may seem a pretty stupid question but I'm out of ideas at the moment and appreciate suggestions.

I have created a quiz interface that should change the question when **NEXT** button is clicked. The next question is loaded as JSON via AJAX call. Now the question contains HTML and I need to use **Rails sanitize helper** to filter tags.

I am not sure how I would use **sanitize** method on <strike>JSON data</strike> data acquired via AJAX call.

Please guide me.

**EDIT:**
The stress was not on JSON data. It was an honest mistake. The issue was the inability to use Rails logic on the data returned by AJAX call.

Comment: I think you need $("#div").html(data);

Comment: I need to use this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize helper method with the returned JSON data.

Comment: So you're getting json data in response, and you need to sanitize it before creating elements and appending to your dom?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Are you using jbuilder to  output json to frontend?

Comment: No. Not using jbuilder.

Comment: Can you show how you're preparing your json for response?

Comment: That is not the issue. Please read the problem statement.

Comment: I read it correct. You're doing everything on js. And once the page has been served, there is no way to use rails sanitize method inside javascript. The only option is you get sanitized response from the server. That's why I asked you to show how you're preparing the json data. Let me give you some examples and alternatives that might work out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already working on the alternative approach. I asked this question just to make sure there is no way of applying Rails logic on data returned by AJAX call. You are one who confirms that. Let's see what others think.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334796/888278), I was able to achieve what I wanted to.

All I had to do was to create a partial template (say, _question.html.erb) for the quiz question container with a form like this:

**_question.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag('/question', :remote => true, :id => 'quiz') do -%>
  ... some code here ...
 <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end -%>
```

Create a route `/question` in routes.rb:

```
  match 'question', :to => 'quiz#question', via: [:post]
```

and in QuizController.rb handle the response:

```
class QuizController < ApplicationController
  def question
    ... some logic here ...

    @ques = ...
    @options = ...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Now, create a question.js.erb to render the template with data:

```
$('#quiz-container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'question',
 :locals => { ques: @ques, options: @options }) %>");
```

The `:remote => true` option in the form does the trick here. It submits the form via ajax. Now, I can use Rails logic inside the partial template that gets the data via AJAX call.